# MS Access Dlookup with text criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use `dlookup` method to use employeeid as an index to search employeename in my Access form. Below is the code I wrote.  employeeid is a short text in my table. The `Dlookup` method cannot return a value(always error) unless I change criteria to ID, default primary key, and eliminate '' symbols in my code.

Also I try to change my table property employeeid column as a number, and eliminate ''symbols, the method also cannot return a value. seems like `dlookup` method can only use default primary key as a criteria in this case. Can anyone help with this?

```vb
Public Function GetEmployeeName() As Variant
    GetEmployeeName = DLookup("[EmployeeName]", "EInfor", "[EmployeeID] = "'& Me.txtEID.Value & "'")   
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You have you " and ' switched in [EmployeeID] =
It should be ' first, and " second. This should work:

```
DLookup("[EmployeeName]", "EInfor", "[EmployeeID] = '" & Me.txtEID.Value & "'")
```

If you don't understand why, I guess I could expand on my explanation but I think it might have been a mistype.

Comment: yes you are right, i have a mistype, but it still show error after I correct my code to yours. I have no idea....

Comment: Have you tried without the []? Those shouldn't be needed there, and depending on how DLookup makes that query they might be throwing the error. [] are used as delimiters when you have spaces like [Employee Name] and it might not work in DLookup.

I can't honestly think of any other problem on your code, it should work. Maybe 'Me.txtEID doesn't hold the correct value? Have you tried debugging it, to see if it's passing the correct value? Maybe it's returning null or an integer?

I've used DLookup to lookup non primary key strings, and it worked just fine.